# How to to do multiple selection in Contacts and add it to edittext

Tags: android, android-contacts

So,i've already implemented adding a contact to my edittext,but i was wondering if we can make multiple selection and add it to a edittext or a textview

Here's my code for OnActivityResult

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        int i;
        if(requestCode == CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor cursor =  getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                    String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    phNo.setText(name + " " + "(" + number + ")");

            }

        }

    }
```

This is something i thought to do for multiple selection

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                    phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneIdx);
                    allNumbers.add(phoneNumber);
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: dude just make it custom for multiple selections fetch all contacts in listview or recyclerview add checkbox and send selected checkbox result to another activity where you wana show selected numbers in edittext

Comment: That would be inefficient,besides i would just be needing like 5 contacts in one go

Comment: 5 contacts in one?

Comment: see my answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43856119/819355